# C Function Pointer Mishap

Tags: c, function, pointers

Okay so I'm trying to learn function pointers. I have a basic function pointer setup like so.

Function to print out linked list:

```
void seq_print(Seq seq, void (* print_func)(void *)){
Node * p = seq->top;
    if(p == NULL){
        printf("%s %c", "There is no data to print.", '\n');
        return;
    }
    while(p != NULL){
        print_func(p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Testing the function:

```
seq_print(s, printFunc(1));
```

I get this error:

```
seq.h:113:32: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 extern void seq_print(Seq seq, (void *) print_func(void *));
```

I'm really not sure what to do, any insight would be helpful.

Comment: You should call it as `seq_print(s, printFunc);`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan there are actual errors here.  Stylistic issues (camelCase versus underscores) are not errors

Comment: @Nirk I means if `void (* print_func)(void *)` is function pointer

Comment: @Nirk Check this [working code](http://codepad.org/IjJwfEUA)

Comment: What's with the downvotes? This isn't an inspirational, revelatory moment, but there seems to be nothing wrong or missing from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have **two** mistakes:

First, notice declaration in error message: in your header file `seq.h`, declaration of function is wrong!

```
 extern void seq_print(Seq seq, (void *) print_func(void *));
 //                             ^      ^ wrong = parenthesis return type
```

it should be:

```
 extern void seq_print(Seq seq, void (*print_func) (void *));
 //                                  ^ correct   ^ = parenthesis function name
```

Second, at calling place.

```
seq_print(s, printFunc(1));
//                    ^^^ you are calling function, and passes returned value
```

should be:

```
seq_print(s, printFunc);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^ don't call pass function address
```

My following code examples will help you to understand better (read comments):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void my_g2(int i, (void*) f(int));  // Mistake: Notice () around void*
void f(int i){
    printf("In f() i =  %d\n", i);        
}
int main(){
    my_g2(10, f(1));  // wrong calling
    return 0;
}
void my_g2(int i, void (*f)(int)){
    printf("In g()\n");
    f(i);
}
```

Check [codepad](http://codepad.org/QcR9KAc5) for working code. You can see error is similar to what you are getting:

```
Line 2: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
In function 'main':
Line 8: error: too many arguments to function 'my_g2'
```

Now correct version of this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void my_g2(int i, void (*f)(int)); // Corrected declaration 
void f(int i){
    printf("In f() i =  %d\n", i);
}
int main(){
    my_g2(10, f);  // corrected calling too 
    return 0;
}
void my_g2(int i, void (*f) (int)){
    printf("In g()\n");
    f(i);
}
```

Now check [codepade](http://codepad.org/Y07onick) for output:

```
In g()
In f() i =  10
```

**Edit:** Adding on the basis of comment.

> But what if it's like `void (*f) (void *)` how do I pass in values to that?

From calling function in main() (in my example = `my_g2`) you need to pass function pointer which you wants call (in my example `f()`) from function you calls in main (that is `my_g2`).

<sup>You wanted to call `f()` from `my_g2()`</sup>

We always pass parameters to function at the time of function calling. So if you wants to pass parameters to `f()` function you have to pass when you call this in `my_g2()`.

A calling expression like below (read comments):

```
seq_print(s, printFunc(1));
             ^ // first printFunc(1) will be called then seq_prints
             pass returned value from printFunc(1)
```

is wrong because if you do so `seq_print` will be called with second paramter value = returned value from function `printFunc(1)`.

To pass void pointer, my following code may help you further:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void my_g2(void* i, void (*f)(void*));
void f(void *i){
    printf("In f(), i =  %d\n", *(int*)i);
    *(int*)i = 20; 
}
int main(){
    int i = 10; 
    my_g2(&i, f);
    printf("Im main, i = %d", i);
    return 0;
}
void my_g2(void* i, void (*f)(void*)){
    printf("In g()\n");
    f(i);
}
```

Output @[codepade](http://codepad.org/gG3vJ6Di):

```
In g()
In f(), i =  10
Im main, i = 20
```

Comment: But what if it's like void (*f) (void *) how do I pass in values to that

Comment: @ManPerson Didn't get you, You mean from calling place? from main?

Answer (score 3):

There's a typo in the forward declaration quoted in the error message. It needs to match the code snippet you posted, with a parameter declaration of `void (* print_func)(void *)`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your header has a typo.  The declaration should be

```
extern void seq_print(Seq seq, void (*print_func)(void *));
```

`(void *)print_func(void *)` is not a valid function pointer declaration.  To declare a function print_func that accepts a void pointer and does not return a value, use `void (*print_func)(void *)`

EDIT: omitting the parens around (*print_func) does create a function pointer but for a function returning a pointer

Comment: `(void *)print_func(void *) is not a valid declaration`, **No** it is a valid function pointer declaration. Where as this `void *print_func(void *)` means return a pointer of `void*` type

Comment: You just traded one typo for another.

Comment: This answer and comments are a mess. `(void *)print_func(void*)` is not a valid function pointer declaration; it's a cast, but that's irrelevant.  To properly declare `print_func` as a function pointer to a function taking a `void *`, and not returning anything (i.e., `void`), declare it `void (*print_func)(void *)`.  You need the parenthesis around `print_func` to get the correct operator precedence .

Comment: @radical7 void *print_func(void*) is a valid pointer, except that it returns a void pointer

Comment: @Nirk Did you mean to write `void * print_func(void*)`?

Comment: @Nirk `void* print_func(void*) is a valid pointer`, **No** this time `print_func` is function that returns a `void pointer` and accept a `void pointer` as function parameter.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan are you saying that `(void *)print_func(void *)` is a valid function pointer declaration?

Comment: @glglgl SO assumed the `*` meant italics

Comment: @Nirk No my comment is very clear, `print_func` is just a function.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan your comment says that `(void *)print_func(void *)` is a valid function pointer declaration, which AFAICT is false

Comment: @Nirk Which comment , I think you misunderstood. In Comment I said: "**`No`** this time `print_func` **is function** that..."

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan "`(void *)print_func(void *) is not a valid declaration`, **No** it is a valid function pointer declaration."