# Pass an objects member function as argument (function pointer)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a pointer to an object 'eventHandler' which has a member function 'HandleButtonEvents':

I call it like this:

```
eventHandler->HandleButtonEvents();
```

Now I want to pass a pointer to the member-function 'HandleButtonEvents()' of the class 'EventHandler' as an argument to another the object 'obj' like in this Stackoverflow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417826/passing-function-pointer):

```
ClassXY obj = ClassXY(eventHandler->HandleButtonEvents);
```

The constructor is declared like this:

```
ClassXY(void(*f)(void));
```

The compiler tells me:

> error : invalid use of non-static member function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pointers to non-static member functions are not the same as a pointer to a non-member function. I recommend you look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) instead.

Comment: It should be `void(DecltypeEventHandler::*f)(void)`.

Comment: @skypjack: can't use that because I can't include the type in that class (include-loop). That's why I try to use the function pointer...

Comment: @C.P. Well, a pointer to function and a pointer to member function are really different beasts.

Comment: @skypjack: Ok. I changed the question. I need a pointer to a member function (of another object)

Comment: @C.P. In order for a pointer-to-member to be usable, C++ has to know what it's a member of. If you can't actually provide that then you'll need to make your class and/or its constructor `template`'d.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) as suggested in my comment makes it very easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class ClassXY
{
    std::function<void()> function;

public:
    ClassXY(std::function<void()> f)
        : function(f)
    {}

    void call()
    {
        function();  // Calls the function
    }
};

class Handler
{
public:
    void HandleButtonEvent()
    {
        std::cout << "Handler::HandleButtonEvent\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Handler* handler = new Handler;

    ClassXY xy(std::bind(&Handler::HandleButtonEvent, handler));

    xy.call();
}
```

[See here for a live example](http://ideone.com/vq2uy3).